# The new PIVOT function in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

Today BigQuery released a new cool function called [PIVOT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator).

Se below how it works:

```
with Produce AS (
  SELECT 'Kale' as product, 51 as sales, 'Q1' as quarter UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 23, 'Q2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 45, 'Q3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 3, 'Q4' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 77, 'Q1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 0, 'Q2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 25, 'Q3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 2, 'Q4')

SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM Produce)
  PIVOT(SUM(sales) FOR quarter IN ('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'))


+---------+----+----+----+----+
| product | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
+---------+----+----+----+----+
| Apple   | 77 | 0  | 25 | 2  |
| Kale    | 51 | 23 | 45 | 3  |
+---------+----+----+----+----+
```

My question is, in the real world, we don't know in advance the quarter values.

I tried to do It more dynamically with:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM Produce)
  PIVOT(SUM(sales) FOR quarter in (select distinct quarter from Produce))
```

Without success. Any clue on how to handle that?

Here is a [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/comments/n9lft0/the_new_pivot_function_in_bigquery/) to reddit cross-post

Comment: You might as well use conditional aggregation -- I personally see no value in `pivot`.  That said, with either method you need dynamic SQL for a dynamic set of columns.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use below - it dynamically builds pivot columns

```
execute immediate (             
select '''select * from (select * from `project.dataset.Produce`)
  pivot(sum(sales) for quarter in ("''' ||  string_agg(quarter, '", "')  || '''"))
'''
from (select distinct quarter from `project.dataset.Produce` order by quarter) 
);
```

Comment: How would this dynamic work in UNPIVOT? I posted the question here but it got marked as duplicate but I don't think it's a duplicate...: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71329838/unpivot-in-bigquery-with-changing-column-set-to-unpivot

Comment: it really does not matter if it is pivot or unpivot case  - technique is the same! not the wording of the question. that is the definition of duplicate question

Comment: How is the technique the same? Here in PIVOT, you are building a text string for the ````for  quarter in (.....)````.

In UNPIVOT, you need to provide the actual columns for the ```FOR ... IN (....)``` part... What am I missing?

Comment: Came across this and thought I'd pick up the unanswered comment. The technique - dynamically building a query and executing it with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` - will still work for `UNPIVOT`, but you would need a query to get the name of the columns, e.g. from the information schema: `SELECT column_name FROM my_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = '<my-table>'`

Comment: this link might be helpful to check: https://towardsdatascience.com/pivot-and-scripting-in-bigquery-cb096ff0eca2

Comment: Note that BigQuery seems to count this as a "script" and emits an error ("configuration.query.destinationTable cannot be set for scripts") if you try to export the result to a table.