# Dynamic Header in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm creating a dashboard where I want to show the items closed per week per category. This is a sample of my table.

| Category | Opened Date | Closed Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | 06/01/2021 | 06/02/2021 |
| Product | 06/02/2021 | 06/07/2021 |
| Feedback | 06/07/2021 | 06/14/2021 |
| Sales | 05/18/2021 | 05/23/2021 |
| Product | 06/01/2021 | 06/01/2021 |
| Feedback | 06/01/2021 | 06/05/2021 |
| Sales | 05/21/2021 | 05/24/2021 |
| Product | 05/21/2021 | 05/26/2021 |
| Product | 06/01/2021 | 06/02/2021 |
| Feedback | 05/31/2021 | 06/13/2021 |
| Sales | 06/02/2021 | 06/06/2021 |
| Product | 06/04/2021 | 06/07/2021 |

This is the result I want to achieve.

Closed category per week

| Category | 05/23/2021 | 05/30/2021 | 06/06/2021 | 06/13/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Product | 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| Feedback | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

I tried to use the SET so I can dynamically create the column but bigQuery shows an error when I use the @ sign. Also it shows literally the column name when I use the column_alias

SET @column_ week1 = DATE_SUBB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAYS)

Any other options to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like you actually want to create a _view_ of the table, where you aggregate the _table source_ by category and completed week, and use the completed week as a pivot.

Answer (score 2):

You can do all the same in one shot

```
execute immediate (             
select '''select * from (
  select replace('_' || (last_day(parse_date('%m/%d/%Y', closed), week) - 6), '-', '_') week, 
    category
  from `project.dataset.table`
  )
  pivot(count(*) for week in ("''' ||  string_agg(week, '", "')  || '''"))
'''
from (select distinct replace('_' || (last_day(parse_date('%m/%d/%Y', closed), week) - 6), '-', '_') week from `project.dataset.table` order by week) 
)
```

with output

[image]

Check out also https://stackoverflow.com/a/67479622/5221944 - can help you in understanding above code

Answer (score 1):

Try [execute_immediate](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate) and [pivot](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator) operator:

```
DECLARE weeks_list STRING;

create temp table input_table as
select 'Sales' as category, '06/02/2021' as closed_date union all
select 'Product', '06/07/2021' union all
select 'Feedback', '06/14/2021' union all
select 'Sales', '05/23/2021' union all
select 'Product', '06/01/2021' union all
select 'Feedback', '06/05/2021' union all
select 'Sales', '05/24/2021' union all
select 'Product', '05/26/2021' union all
select 'Product', '06/02/2021' union all
select 'Feedback', '06/13/2021' union all
select 'Sales', '06/06/2021' union all
select 'Product', '06/07/2021';

create temp table normalized_table as select category, FORMAT_DATE('_%m_%d_%Y', DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', closed_date), WEEK)) as closed_week from input_table;
SET weeks_list = (select string_agg(distinct '"' || closed_week || '"') from normalized_table);
execute immediate 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT category, closed_week FROM normalized_table) PIVOT(count(*) FOR closed_week IN (' || weeks_list || '))';
```

[image]

P.S.

You can skip creating temporary `normalized_table` and `weeks_list` variable:

```
execute immediate (
  select '''
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT 
        category,
        FORMAT_DATE("_%m_%d_%Y", DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE("%m/%d/%Y", closed_date), WEEK)) as closed_week
      FROM input_table)
      PIVOT(count(*) FOR closed_week IN (''' || string_agg(distinct '"' || closed_week || '"') || '''))
  '''
  from (
    select
      category,
      FORMAT_DATE("_%m_%d_%Y", DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE("%m/%d/%Y", closed_date), WEEK)) as closed_week
    from input_table
  )
);
```