# Google Firebase and Big Query : SQL Array to Columns

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am attempting to split a string ("item1,item2,item3") that is an event param (key = "to_split", value.string_value = "item1,item2,item3") into multiple columns in Google BigQuery.
Currently, I have:

```
SELECT
    event_name,
    PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", event_date) as date, 
    TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) as timestamp,
   (
     SELECT split(params.value.string_value, ',')
     FROM UNNEST(event_params) as params
     WHERE key = 'event_param-key_to_filter'
   ),
FROM `firebase.analytics.table`
```

Which will give results like:

| event_name | date | timestamp | f0_ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Example Event | 2021-06-15 | 2021-06-15 10:08:41.634055 UTC | Item\nItem\nItem\nItem |

(Formatting doesn't like it, but the split turns the items into an array)

I am trying to get results such that I have:

| event_name | date | timestamp | item0 | item1 | item2 | item... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Example Event | 2021-06-15 | 2021-06-15 10:08:41.634055 UTC | Item | Item | Item | etc... |

Is there a good way to split this item array into columns along the same row in SQL for BigQuery? I've been stuck on this for quite some time.

Best

Comment: do you have fixed count of such items to split?

Comment: It's not always a fixed amount, no. But it has an amount maximum (6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array references:

```
SELECT t.*,
       items[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)] as item_1,
       items[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)] as item_2,
       items[SAFE_ORDINAL(3)] as item_3,
       items[SAFE_ORDINAL(4)] as item_4
FROM (SELECT event_name, PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", event_date) as date, 
             TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) as timestamp,
             (SELECT split(params.value.string_value, ',') 
              FROM UNNEST(event_params) as params
              WHERE key = 'event_param-key_to_filter'
             ) items
      FROM `firebase.analytics.table` t
     ) t
```

Comment: This gives me an error message: ```No matching signature for function SPLIT for argument types: ARRAY<STRING>, STRING. Supported signatures: SPLIT(STRING, [STRING]); SPLIT(BYTES, BYTES) at [2:8]``` on the first `split(items,...`

Comment: Changing to `t.*, items[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)] as item_1, items[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)] as item_2, ...` fixed this. The answer above would be best for an array like `["[subitem/subitem/subitem]","[subitem/subitem/subitem]",...]` I believe.
Thank you for the post! This has really saved me

Comment: Also, @Gordon Linoff if you update with the comment change above, (or add as a split section answer) I'll accept the answer as the fix

Comment: @SpencerPollock . . . Duh.  The split is already in the subquery.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select * from (
  select * except(items) from (
  SELECT
    event_name,
    PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", event_date) as date, 
    TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) as timestamp,
   (
     SELECT split(params.value.string_value, ',')
     FROM UNNEST(event_params) as params
     WHERE key = 'event_param-key_to_filter'
   ) items,
  FROM `firebase.analytics.table`
  ), unnest(items) item with offset
)
pivot (max(item) for offset in (0 as item0, 1 as item1, 2 as item2, 3 as item3, 4 as item4, 5 as item5))
```

Also, check out below answers to see how you can make dynamic PIVOT so it will work for any number of items if you don't know in advance the max count

[Dynamic Header in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68062341/5221944)
[The new PIVOT function in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67479622/5221944)

Btw, below is that dynamic pivot version, I mentioned above

```
execute immediate (select '''
select * from (
  select * except(items) from (
  SELECT
    event_name,
    PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", event_date) as date, 
    TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) as timestamp,
   (
     SELECT split(params.value.string_value, ',')
     FROM UNNEST(event_params) as params
     WHERE key = 'event_param-key_to_filter'
   ) items,
  FROM `firebase.analytics.table`
  ), unnest(items) item with offset
)
pivot (max(item) for offset in (''' || string_agg(pos || ' as item' || pos, ', ') || ''')) '''
from 
  unnest(generate_array(0, (
    select max(array_length(split(params.value.string_value, ','))) - 1
    from `firebase.analytics.table`, unnest(event_params) as params
    where key = 'event_param-key_to_filter'
  ))) pos
)
```