# How to convert or transpose rows to columns in SQL without using pivot?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, transpose

I have faced one issue while getting data transposed in SQL. for e.g table given below

| id | source_name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cp | x |
| 1 | cp | y |
| 1 | hi | a |
| 2 | li | b |
| 2 | cp | c |
| 2 | li | d |
| 3 | li | e |

I need this table in below format (transposed but with string aggregation)-

| id | cp | hi | li | mi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x,y | a | null | null |
| 2 | c | null | b,d | null |
| 3 | null | null | null | d |

With the current sql query, I am getting table in below format.

| id | cp | hi | li | mi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | a | null | null |
| 2 | c | null | b | null |
| 3 | null | null | null | d |

Can anyone tweak the query or suggest new query in SQL (Platform - Bigquery)?

Current query -

```
select id, any_value(if(source_name = 'cp', value, null)) as cp,
any_value(if(source_name = 'hi', value, null)) as hi,
any_value(if(source_name = 'li', value, null)) as li
any_value(if(source_name = 'mi', value, null)) as mi
from table_name group by id
```

Comment: just curious - why `without using pivot`? what use case you have that you don't want to do it best way (which is pivot)? :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [STRING_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#string_agg) instead of `any_value`:

```
select id, string_agg(if(source_name = 'cp', value, null)) as cp,
string_agg(if(source_name = 'hi', value, null)) as hi,
string_agg(if(source_name = 'li', value, null)) as li
string_agg(if(source_name = 'mi', value, null)) as mi
from table_name group by id
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [PIVOT operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator) instead

```
select *
from `project.dataset.table`
pivot (string_agg(value) for source_name in ('cp', 'hi', 'li', 'mi'))
```

If applied to sample data in your question

[image]

output is

[image]

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/67479622/5221944 if you want to make it dynamically build list of columns for you