# BigQuery average column by condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Assume I have the following simplified data in BigQuery:

```
WITH sales_log AS
 (
  SELECT 'John' as employee, 'ABC' client, 1234.56 sales, "phone" sale_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John' as employee, 'ABC' client, 9857.56 sales, "online" sale_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John' as employee, 'XYZ' client, 5678.56 sales, "phone" sale_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John' as employee, 'XYZ' client, 64875.25 sales, "online" sale_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mary' as employee, 'ABC' client, 456.58 sales, "phone" sale_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mary' as employee, 'ABC' client, 11585.58 sales, "online" sale_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mary' as employee, 'XYZ' client, 4578.52 sales, "phone" sale_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mary' as employee, 'XYZ' client, 56853.45 sales, "online" sale_type
  )
SELECT employee, AVG(sales) AS avg_sales
FROM sales_log
GROUP BY employee
```

I can easily get the average of the employees' sales.

Is there an easy way to also get the average of EACH TYPE of sale in a single row? So that the output would be like:

| employee | avg_sales | avg_phone_sales | avg_online_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 20411.4825 | 3456.56 | 37366.405 |
| Mary | 18368.5325 | 2517.55 | 34219.515 |

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple approaches:

- DEMO's at bottom:
- If the Types are limited you can use case expressions for each column.
- If they are "Dynamic" then you need a dynamic pivot. (Several online examples exist; but this means dynamic SQL which can be prone to SQL injection)
- NOTE: Typically data formatting such as this is done in the UI not the SQL.
- NOTE: Use of Null ensures the "blank" values don't impact your average.

.

```
WITH sales_log AS
 (
  SELECT 'John' as employee, 'ABC' client, 1234.56 sales, 'phone' sale_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John' as employee, 'ABC' client, 9857.56 sales, 'online' sale_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John' as employee, 'XYZ' client, 5678.56 sales, 'phone' sale_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John' as employee, 'XYZ' client, 64875.25 sales, 'online' sale_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mary' as employee, 'ABC' client, 456.58 sales, 'phone' sale_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mary' as employee, 'ABC' client, 11585.58 sales, 'online' sale_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mary' as employee, 'XYZ' client, 4578.52 sales, 'phone' sale_type UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mary' as employee, 'XYZ' client, 56853.45 sales, 'online' sale_type
  )
SELECT employee, AVG(sales) AS avg_sales, 
       AVG(case when sale_type = 'phone' then sales else NULL end) as AVG_PhoneSales, 
       AVG(case when sale_type = 'online' then sales else NULL end) as AVG_OnLineSales
FROM sales_log
GROUP BY employee
```

GIVING US:

```
+----------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| employee |     avg_sales      |  AVG_phonesales       | AVG_onlinesales    |
+----------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| Mary     | 18368.532500000000 | 2517.5500000000000000 | 34219.515000000000 |
| John     | 20411.482500000000 | 3456.5600000000000000 | 37366.405000000000 |
+----------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=718bdc9c2b9267f48cefa47139579f9c) : While not google big-query the syntax would be the same in this use case.  The Dynamic SQL or Dynamic pivot would be different.

Example of Dynamic: [The new PIVOT function in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67479396/the-new-pivot-function-in-bigquery)

Comment: @RobE.  take a look at the other answer.  It seems like it's more inline with google's bigquery.  Not that I don't appreciate the positive feedback, I just want you to have the best answer for your problem, and for others.  This is just a common design pattern I use when not all tools support pivot the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select employee, sale_type, avg(sales) as avg_sales
  from sales_log
  group by rollup (employee, sale_type)
  having not employee is null
)
pivot (min(avg_sales) avg for ifnull(sale_type || '_sales', 'sales') in ('sales', 'phone_sales', 'online_sales'))
```

if applied to sample data in y our question - output is

[image]

Comment: Another excellent suggestion. Thank you! I have used your answers quite a bit this week LOL.