# pivot function in Bigquery for transpose, wrong value falling in

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use pivot function to transpose rows however action_type=4 keeps falling to the wrong column after I ran my query. Below is the sample data:

| SessionId | action_type | products |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 122 | 3 | 5 |
| 122 | 4 | 1 |
| 127 | 3 | 2 |
| 189 | 4 | 1 |

Ideal output will look like below:

| SessionId | action_type_1 | products_1 | action_type_2 | products_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 122 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 127 | 3 | 2 |  |  |
| 189 |  |  | 4 | 1 |

I have written below query trying to do the transpose:

```
select * from
(select * except (SessionId),
max(SessionId) over win SessionId,
row_number() over (win order by SessionId, action_type, products) tab

from 
`xxx.sample.xxx` 
window win as (partition by SessionId) 
)
pivot (
any_value (action_type) as action_type ,
any_value(products) as products for tab in (1,2))
```

However this output has returning some strange results, for example I see value 4 under action_type_1, which is not what I expected. action_type_1 should only have value 3 because I wanted to define action_type_1=3 and action_type_2=4. Can anyone help look at my query? Any advises are appreciated!

Comment: do  you have just two action types (3 and 4)?!

Comment: Hi Mikhail, yes I only have 2 types (3 and 4), value 4 would fall under action_type_1 after running my query which is mainly what I am looking for help here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, below is what you are looking for

```
select * from your_table
pivot (
  any_value (action_type) as action_type ,
  any_value(products) as products 
  for action_type in (3,4)  
)
```

with output

[image]

so, as you can see - instead of relying on offset  - you just simply go directly off of action type!

In case if for some reason you need output as _1 and _2 - use below trick

```
select * from your_table
pivot (
  any_value (action_type) as action_type ,
  any_value(products) as products 
  for case action_type when 3 then 1 when 4 then 2 end in (1,2)  
)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: amazing solutions thank you Mikhail! Just a quick question regards to the first solution, I wonder how the query would be written if we have many more action types?

Comment: sure. if you have just few types known in advance  - you can just manually enlist them otherwise you should use dynamic pivoting  - there are plenty of posts here on SO covering this technique - me personally i answered quite a number of such questions  - just do quick search here on SO - here is one of those  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67479622/5221944

Comment: learned, so awesome how you did it in the dynamic way :) thanks for sharing knowledge with us all