PIVOT without hardcoding values?
With the following PIVOT:
with purchases as (
  SELECT * from UNNEST([
    STRUCT(1 as id,'Tom' as buyer, 108 as cost),
    (2,'Brady', 17),
    (3,'Tom', 19)
  ])
) select * from (select * except(id) from purchases)
PIVOT (SUM(cost) FOR buyer in ('Tom', 'Brady'))


I specify the names manually in the expression list after IN. However, what if I have 500 names? Do I have to specify all those, or can I just say something like "the buyer column" ? How could I basically do:
PIVOT (SUM(cost) FOR buyer) -- excluding the IN -- I want all values !


PIVOT do not support dynamic values, but you can use EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE do generate a dynamic query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67479396/the-new-pivot-function-in-bigquery

Does this answer your question? The new PIVOT function in BigQuery

@DamiãoMartins oh what a shame!
